# Any help correcting this/explaining it would be appreciated

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Trying to write a function for a button using JavaScript. I want the function to simultaneously hide some ID elements and show other ID elements. This is what I have so far. It doesn't work. I am very new at JavaScript so there is a high probability that my code is garbage.

```
function mlbShowTeamsMap() {
  document.getElementById("mlbTeamsMap").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("mlbTeamsList").style.display = "block";
  var mlbOther = ["nflTeamsList", "nflTeamsMap", "nhlTeamsList", "nhlTeamsMap", "nbaTeamsList", "nbaTeamsMap"];
  mlbOther.forEach(hide);

  function hide() {
    style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `forEach` to iterate your array `mlbOther`. Now `forEach` takes in an array and has a callback function which gives the first parameter as the element of the array. Your callback function `hide` therefore needs to define a variable to accept this parameter. Please find the code below.

**Corrected Syntax**

```
function mlbShowTeamsMap() {
  document.getElementById("mlbTeamsMap").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("mlbTeamsList").style.display = "block";

  var mlbOther = ["nflTeamsList", "nflTeamsMap", "nhlTeamsList", "nhlTeamsMap", "nbaTeamsList", "nbaTeamsMap"];

  mlbOther.forEach(hide);

  function hide(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

**Alternate Syntax using the arrow function**

```
function mlbShowTeamsMap() {
  document.getElementById("mlbTeamsMap").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("mlbTeamsList").style.display = "block";

  var mlbOther = ["nflTeamsList", "nflTeamsMap", "nhlTeamsList", "nhlTeamsMap", "nbaTeamsList", "nbaTeamsMap"];

  mlbOther.forEach(id => {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

**Read More**

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thank you, it did not work though. When I clicked the button, it showed, but it did not hide. I tried copying and pasting each one. I appreciate your help.

Comment: should I put a # for each element in the array?

Comment: @MATH9 since you are using `getElementById`, you do not need the `#`

Comment: ok. at this point then not sure why it isn't working?

Comment: you will need to update the OP

Comment: it works!  ".style" was missing before ".display". Thank you!!!